# MongoDB replSet takes forever to initiate

Tags: mongodb, replication

I'm setting up a replica set on my localhost just to get practice working with the necessary commands. I'm doing it both at home and at work. At home, the `rs.initiate()` command takes about three seconds to run, and it takes about another two or three minutes for `rs.status()` to give me all states that are either `PRIMARY` or `SECONDARY`. This is about what I expected.

But when I do it at work, `rs.initiate()` takes almost 7 minutes just to give me back my prompt in the mongo shell, then another 10 minutes before the states are all `PRIMARY` or `SECONDARY`. In the meantime, the one from which I initiated the connection is in `SECONDARY` or `PRIMARY` and the other two are `RECOVERING`. They just sit there, `RECOVERING`, for ten minutes.

While the `rs.initiate()` command is running, the `mongod` to which I've connected (port 10001) keeps spitting out stuff about "allocating datafile", then "done allocating datafile", then "allocating new datafile", and so on until it's got about a dozen of those files. The other two just sit there with "replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)" the whole time.

While I'm checking `rs.status()`, the two secondaries keep accepting and dropping connections, and allocating datafiles much like the primary does during the first step.

So is it supposed to take this long? And, if so, why does my machine at home do it in seconds? The only difference is that the one I'm running at home is 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

Comment: Does your work machine have a lot of data?  And your home machine not as much (or none)?  The more data that you have, the longer it will take the replica set to create properly.  (As it needs to duplicate the data throughout).

Comment: are they different os / different file system type / different machine size / vm? Sounds like you get normal performance at home and something strange at work

Comment: Actually you should be able to check in the log file what is taking such a long time.

Answer (score 3):

How much available disk space is there on your work environment's disk?  MongoDB by default allocates for its oplog (the "local" database) 5% of available disk space.  My guess based on the information you provided is that your available disk space is much larger on your work machine than your home machine.

If you wait until your the rs.initiate() is complete (i.e. you see PRIMARY) before you try starting the other nodes, I think you'll see results that you expect.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. But it seems that @angela is right. On production the hard dis was much bigger than on my working machine. And it just a bit longer but in the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you're facing this issue , try restarting mongodb. i faced this problem with fresh db. I resolved it by restarting mongodb.